# SSL_set_tlsext_host_name crashes

Tags: c++, ssl, boost, openssl, boost-beast

I'm trying to use [scio_beast](https://github.com/cw-zift/scio-beast) in a project. I understand its rather unfinished, but that should not matter much. I've managed to get it working pretty well.

I'm trying to connect to a server behind CloudFlare now, an I understand I need SNI for that to work.

Given the following:

```cpp
using tcp           = boost::asio::ip::tcp;     //  <boost/asio/ip/tcp.hpp>
namespace websocket = boost::beast::websocket;  //  <boost/beast/websocket.hpp>
namespace ssl       = boost::asio::ssl;         //  <boost/asio/ssl.hpp>

typedef websocket::stream<ssl::stream<tcp::socket>>  SecureWebSocket;
typedef std::unique_ptr<SecureWebSocket>            SecureWebSocketPtr;

// ...

SecureWebSocketPtr m_wss;

m_sslContext = std::make_shared<ssl::context>(ssl::context::tlsv12_client);
m_wss.reset(new SecureWebSocket(m_ios, *m_sslContext.get()));

auto ssl = m_wss->next_layer().native_handle();
auto host = m_connectOptions.host.c_str();
SSL_set_tlsext_host_name(m_wss->next_layer().native_handle(), host);
```

It does not seem to matter much where I call `SSL_set_tlsext_host_name` (e.g. before resolving, before `async_handshake`), it always crashes trying to execute 0x0000000000000000.

Comment: Trying to *execute* 0x0000000000000000 suggests that `SSL_set_tlsext_host_name` *itself* is likely a NULL *function pointer*, not a static-linked function call. So whatever is loading OpenSSL into memory isn't assigning the pointer to `SSL_set_tlsext_host_name` before you try to call it.

Comment: `SSL_ctrl` (the function behind the macro `SSL_set_tlsext_host_name`) must be there, stepped into it a bit in asm view. The `call` leads to a `jmp` (the dll import I assume) and I've seen a few more instructions behind it, including more calls/jumps. So it must be something inside OpenSSL that goes wrong. When I let it continue to the crash, the debugger showed a solid NULL on top of the stack above my function where `SSL_set_tlsext_host_name` is called, the return address pointing to the next line.

Comment: Oh, right, forgot that `SSL_set_tlsext_host_name` is a macro wrapper for `SSL_ctrl`. Is How is `m_ios` initialized? And does `m_wss->next_layer().native_handle()` return a non-null `SSL*` pointer?

Comment: m_ios is just `boost::asio::io_service m_ios;`, no explicit ctor call. Should that even affect the OpenSSL call? The returned native handle is non-null, and so is the hostname.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Turns out this was a linking problem: The app uses another library (WebRTC) that uses boringssl. Somehow the linker didn't complain about duplicate symbols when linking OpenSSL after WebRTC and silently used boringssl's functions. Both MSVC and gcc do it.

I solved it by moving the websocket/OpenSSL code into a dll, which allows it to properly link against OpenSSL independently from the app.

Not the prettiest solution, but building WebRTC with OpenSSL doesn't seem to be really supported or at least maintained.